# Object is not stored in EhCache

Tags: java, ehcache

Please help me to understand why there is no files or anything in `D:/DataStore_ehCache`.But there is not Exception or Error in execution of the program

```
Profit profit = new Profit();
profit.setId(1);
profit.setAmt("1000");
profit.setLastupdate(new Date());

DiskStoreConfiguration disk =new DiskStoreConfiguration();
disk.setPath("D:/DataStore_ehCache");

Configuration cacheManagerConfig = new Configuration();
cacheManagerConfig.addDiskStore(disk);

//Create a CacheManager using defaults
CacheManager manager = CacheManager.create(cacheManagerConfig);

//Create a Cache specifying its configuration.
CacheConfiguration cacheconfig = new CacheConfiguration("Profit",1000);
cacheconfig.memoryStoreEvictionPolicy(MemoryStoreEvictionPolicy.LFU)
.eternal(false)
.timeToLiveSeconds(60)
.timeToIdleSeconds(30)
.diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds(0)
.persistence(new PersistenceConfiguration().strategy(Strategy.LOCALTEMPSWAP));

Cache profitCache = new Cache(cacheconfig);
manager.addCache(profitCache);

Element element = new Element(profit.getId(), profit);
manager.getTransactionController().begin();
profitCache.put(element);
manager.getTransactionController().commit();
System.out.println("Element put in Store");
manager.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Local Temp Swap" persistence strategy does not persist to disk between restarts. Once you shut down the cache manager, you lose everything stored in the cache. Unfortunately with the standard open source version of Ehcache, you cannot persist between restarts. To enable that feature, you need to set the persistence strategy to "localRestartable", which is only available in Terracotta's Big Memory Go offering. Big Memory Go is free to use with restrictions, but it is not open source.

In past versions of Ehcache it was possible to persist to disk by setting a cache's overflowToDisk and diskPersistent properties to true. However as of Ehcache 2.6, those options have been removed in favor of the persistence strategies mentioned above.

See [their documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation/configuration/fast-restart) on persistence strategies for more information.